# How to make Bootstrap 3 columns align properly when they are different heights?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with Bootstrap 3 columns. When the 12 columns are filled and I keep adding columns they are stacking under them(normal behavior). But if the columns on top of them have different height, a gutter is created. Is there a way of removing it so they can align properly(with no space)? (desktop)

```
<div class="row content clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-4 itms">
        <div class="user">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail-custom">
                <img src="logo.jpg" alt="User">
            </a>
            <p>Posted by:</p>
            <p>User</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.col-md-4{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
min-height: 100px;
        }

.itms {
border: 2px solid rgba(54, 21, 21, 1);
}
.user{
padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
max-width: 80px;
border-right: 2px solid rgba(54, 21, 21, 1);
}

.user img{
 margin-top: 5px;
 max-width: 77px;
 max-height: 77px;
 margin: -5px 0 0 -5px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(54, 21, 21, 1);
 }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

You either have the columns with rows separating them so they don't shift under each other, or (as I do) use flex. You can also do other things if you have to support IE8 for equal height columns. Equal height is the only way I know to make them not shift like your issues are indicating. ([How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)).

Here's a simple Bootply to show you how this can be done: http://bootply.com/127827

Create a custom class to append to row with these values:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
flex:1 0 auto;
```

Comment: No, I'm not using a different row for each column(all the columns are in the same row), and the columns are shifting under each other and I don't want all the columns to be one exact height :/, thank you for your time :).

Comment: Another option is to do a 3 column and populate inside.

Comment: Great idea, and do the queries for the mobile!!